# Is IExtensibleDataObject interface needed for shared contracts

Tags: wcf

We are developing a WCF service for internal company use. The entities (data contracts) are in a separate assembly and are referenced by both the service and applications that consume the service.

Is there any need to implement the IExtensibleDataObject interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `IExtensibleDataObject` (IEDO) is used if you expect your contract to receive (e.g., in a service call) more data than is listed in the data members. If you have the same assembly on both client and service this will not be the case.

For a more detailed description of the scenarios where IEDO is useful, check the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/27/wcf-extensibility-other-serialization-extensions.aspx.